# Creating generic JsonPatchMapper in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have been trying to create generic json patch mapper, which would:

- take an `targetBean` and convert it to JsonNode
- apply `patch` to it
- convert patched JsonNode back to

Here is my attempt, but now I'm getting an error saying **Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.**
This error occurs on line where I do return

> ...treeToValue(patched, T::class.java

Code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.github.fge.jsonpatch.JsonPatch
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.function.BiFunction

@Component
class JsonPatchMapper<T>: BiFunction<T, JsonPatch, T> {

    private val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    
    override fun apply(targetBean: T, patch: JsonPatch): T {
        val target = objectMapper.convertValue(targetBean, JsonNode::class.java)
        val patched = patch.apply(target)

        return objectMapper.treeToValue(patched, T::class.java)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)